# ETL / ELT pipelines - Metainformation about the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, data-warehouse, data-lakehouse

how do you add metainformation about the used ETL / ELT code (and version of this ELT code) to the produced sink files / tables?

Do u consider it as required to have information like "PipelineID" or "DataProductionTime" in the targetfolder?

Comment: To answer your first question we would need to know which ETL solution you are using. Your second question is asking for an opinion and therefore out of scope for this forum (plus the fact you should only ask one question per post)

Comment: Am using Azure data factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do you add metainformation about the used ETL / ELT code (and version of this ELT code) to the produced sink files / tables?

You can do it using the **pipeline dynamic content** and **additional column in copy activity**.

**This is my source file:**

[image]

In source of copy activity use additional column.

[image]

In ADF you can find meta information about the pipeline in **System variables** of dynamic content.

[image]

**Target file in sink folder:**

[image]

> Do u consider it as required to have information like "PipelineID" or "DataProductionTime" in the targetfolder?

All this depends on your requirement like if you want to know by which pipeline you are getting data you can use this.

Comment: Nice, runId is good as info here. Further i'll need the branch name -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598386/azure-datafactory-get-current-branch-as-parameter