# Azure datafactory - Get current branch as parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

Am using Azure datafactory in combination with git:

[image]

During execution of a pipeline, can i get the current branch name as pipeline parameter, maybe like this:?
[image]

Wished output (additional column with branch name):
[image]

Sources: [ETL / ELT pipelines - Metainformation about the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588596/etl-elt-pipelines-metainformation-about-the-pipeline/74597157#74597157)

Comment: There is no dynamic for getting `Git branch name`. The meta information about pipeline is `System variables` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround to achieve your scenario is follow below steps:

**create pipeline parameter with type string and default value as your branch name**.

[image]

In source of copy activity use additional column and value as parameter you created for branch name.

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Only possible system variables are as mentioned in [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables) are as below:

[image]